# how to display gridview in tabsx in yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2

I am using tabx widget and want to display gridview in it. how to do that ?

tabsx is in frontend and gridview(CRUD) is from backend ..then is it possible to display gridview in frontend?

here is code index.php

```
 echo TabsX::widget([
    'position' => TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
    'align' => TabsX::ALIGN_LEFT,
    'items' => [
        [
            'label' => 'gridview',
            'content' => $content_grid,//**want gridview index page to open here... how to do it.. views\companies\index.php**
            'active' => true
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Basic Search',
            'content' => $content_basic_search,
            'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'font-weight:bold'],
            'options' => ['id' => 'myveryownID'],
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Dropdown',
            'items' => [
                 [
                     'label' => 'DropdownA',
                     'content' => 'DropdownA, Anim pariatur cliche...',
                 ],
                 [
                     'label' => 'DropdownB',
                     'content' => 'DropdownB, Anim pariatur cliche...',
                 ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

how to get the gridview in tabsx??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
        'label' => 'gridview',
        'content' => $yourModel->getGridView(),
        'active' => true
```

Then define the getGridView funciton in $yourModel:

```
public function getGridView($id)
{
    $searchModel = new YourModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('_view_index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

or
render the grid directly on your view:

```
'label' => 'gridview',
'content' => $this->render('_grid' , ['dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,'searchModel' => $searchModel]),
'active' => true
```

Comment: this tabsx is in frontend of yii2 advanced app and gridview is in backend.. then how render that file backend/view/companies/index.php